# Generating a random number larger than the previous one

Tags: java

I have an array of doubles and want to generate a random number that is bigger than the previous one. This is what I have so far:

```
public void randomGenerator(double[] array)
{
    double[] newArray = new double[3];
    array = newArray;
    Random rand = new Random();

    for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        double rangeMin = 0;
        double rangeMax = 10;
        double randomValue = rangeMin + (rangeMax - rangeMin) * rand.nextDouble();

        if(array[i] >array[i-1])
        {
            array[i] = randomValue;
        }   

    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));     
}
```

I am unsure about how to go about this as this generates an array of 0.0.

Comment: `new Random().doubles(3, 0, 10).sorted().toArray()`

Comment: @shmosel which `Random` is this? Java8?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes.

Comment: Use a `while` loop instead of a `for`, and only increment `i` when you actually assign a value to `array[i]`.

Comment: @KevinAnderson or keep the `for` and decrement `i` and `continue`